# comparing dates (with between) using TO_DATE vs TRUNC() or other efficient methods

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a date in one field (outcomes_date) that is really a date with zeros due to an ETL process so that it comes out as 01JUN2019:00:00:00 -
The other two fields (admdt and disdt) have the time stamps-

If don't use use the trunc function I will potentially miss some entries where the admdt is the same date as the outcome_date.

According to an another developer here-trunc is expensive in terms of processing, but I read that I should never to_Date a date either.

Any tips on efficiencies appreciated.

i.e. 
where trunc(outcome_date) between trunc(admdt) and trunc(disdt)

Comment: I've never had a performance issue using trunc.  Should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not that `TRUNC()` is expensive.  It is that, if column "X" is indexed, any function (`TRUNC()` or otherwise) on that column will prevent Oracle from using the index.

So, unless you want to create a function-based index on the expression `TRUNC(outcome_date)`, you are better off not using `TRUNC()`.

An alternative:

```
WHERE outcome_date BETWEEN trunc(admdt) and trunc(disdt)+1-INTERVAL `1` SECOND
```

Comment: Thanks on how Oracle uses or not uses the index w/ trunc. If the admdt and disdt are indexed (and they may be although) outcome_date is not then would the use of trunc on those  admdt and disdt vars be impacted-thanks

Comment: Often questions on SO are simplified / abstracted from the "real" problem, so I answered generally.  In your real situation, if `outcome_date`, `admdt`, and `disdt` are all truly columns from the same table, then indexes aren't going to help much unless you take a different indexing approach altogether (e.g., a function-based index on some expression based on the intervals between the dates).

Comment: Ok-Thanks. The outcome_date is from another table I produce dynamically vs the other two vars. the advice helped as it cut down the time  to a 1/5 from ~10 min to ~2!